# decltype(auto) in new initializer?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

In C++11 I can do the following just fine:

```
auto a = new auto{42};
```

But none of the following work in any compiler I've tried:

```
decltype(auto) a = new decltype(auto){42};
auto a = new decltype(auto){42};
```

How do I use `decltype(auto)` in a new initializer in C++11?

Comment: Why would you want to anyway?

Answer (score 5):

`decltype(auto)` is a [C++14 feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Alternate_type_deduction_on_declaration) !